# android - ViewPager (with TabHost) Fragment GetItem being called multiple time

Tags: android, android-listview, android-viewpager, android-tabhost, android-arrayadapter

I spent hours in searching some usefull post about my specific issue without success.

All the posts talks about setting list view layout to "fill_parent". But I don't have an explicit List View in my layout.

Here is the code:

**TabsAdapter:**

```
public class TabsAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter implements
    TabHost.OnTabChangeListener, ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener, IconPagerAdapter {
.
.
     @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        TabInfo info = mTabs.get(position);
        return Fragment.instantiate(mContext, info.clss.getName(),
            info.args);
    }
.
.
```

**ArrayAdapter:**

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = null;
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflator = context.getLayoutInflater();
        view = inflator.inflate(
                R.layout.list_activity_segnalazioni_archivio_riga, null);
        final ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.codiceEsterno = (TextView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.list_activity_segnalazione_archivio_riga_textview_codice_esterno);
        viewHolder.data = (TextView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.list_activity_segnalazione_archivio_riga_textview_data);
        viewHolder.posizione = (TextView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.list_activity_segnalazione_archivio_riga_textview_posizione);
        viewHolder.codiceEsterno.setFocusable(false);
        viewHolder.codiceEsterno.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
        viewHolder.data.setFocusable(false);
        viewHolder.data.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
        viewHolder.posizione.setFocusable(false);
        viewHolder.posizione.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);


        viewHolder.removeButton = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.list_activity_segnalazione_archivio_riga_imagebutton_remove);
        viewHolder.removeButton.setFocusable(false);
        viewHolder.removeButton.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
        viewHolder.previewImage = (ImageView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.row_image);

            .
            .
            .
        view.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        view = convertView;
    }

    ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    try {
        holder.codiceEsterno.setText(segnalazioni.get(position).getCodiceEsterno());
        holder.data.setText(DateUtils.formatToHumanDate(segnalazioni.get(
                position).getDataInizio()));

        String address = segnalazioni.get(position).getToponimo();
        if (segnalazioni.get(position).getCivico() != null
                && !segnalazioni.get(position).getCivico().equals("")) {
            address = address.concat(", ").concat(
                    segnalazioni.get(position).getCivico().toString()
                    .toUpperCase(Locale.ITALY));
        }
        holder.posizione.setText(address);

        Map<String, Object> sqlParams = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        sqlParams.put("identita", segnalazioni.get(position).getIdStorico());

            // This retrieve a base64 image from the sqlite.
            // Getting called more times that needed gives me an incredible cpu overhead
            **String thumb64 = SegnalamiApplication.abatis.executeForString("getAllFileDatiByIdEntitaForThumb", sqlParams);**

            if(thumb64 != null)
            {
                holder.previewImage.setImageBitmap(BitmapUtils.base64ToBitmap(thumb64));
            }

        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return view;
    }
```

**xml layout (most important different thing than the other GetItem posts):**

```
<TabHost
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp" />

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/archivio_pager"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

At this point each item is called 5 time, that gives me an high overhead with a low number of elements (5 item means 25 GetItem calling).

I sincerely hope we will solve the issue together.

L.F.

Answer (score -1):

instead of `fragmentPagerAdapter` try `fragmentStatePagerAdapter`.